# Opening two files simultaneously on a "with" context

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

I'm wondering if there is a construction in Python 3 that allows me to open two (or more) files on the same `with` context.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

file1 = Path('file1.txt')
file2 = Path('file2.txt')

with file1.open() as f1 and file2.open() as f2:
    '''do something with file handles...
```

The code above is obviously invalid, which leads to this question.

Comment: Try `and` → `,`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use comma:

```
from pathlib import Path

file1 = Path('file1.txt')
file2 = Path('file2.txt')

with file1.open() as f1, file2.open() as f2:
    '''do something with file handles...
```

[Documentation for `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) covers the case for multiple context expressions.

Comment: Thanks, @sanyash. Extra bonus for pointing me the documentation. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The correct one is `with file1.open() as f1, file2.open() as f2:`

Depending on what you want to do with `f1` and `f2` you can use directly
[`pathlib.Path.read_text()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.write_text) and [`pathlib.Path.write_text()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.write_text), e.g.

```
from pathlib import Path

file1 = Path('file1.txt')
content = file1.read_text()
print(content)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm used to ```pathlib.Path()``` methods. My interest was on the ```with``` context.